# Using getline() to read input (with spaces) from file into a structure

Tags: c++, structure, getline

I am currently in a C++ data structures class and I am extremely new to c++. My goal here is to read lines from a file and store them into a structure.  The lines contain elements of a book. My problem is that some lines have spaces, and I'm not sure how to properly read them into a structure. I can't seem to use `getline()` correctly to read the lines into each element of the structure. If I run it as is, I get the message `error: expected primary expression before 'infile'`.  Apologies if this post isn't formatted correctly, this is also my first stack overflow post! Any help??

This is what my structure looks like:

```
typedef struct book {
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
    char publisher[100];
    float price;
    char isbn[100];
    int pages;
    int copies;
} Book;
```

And this is how I am trying to read lines into the structure:

```
for (int i=0; i < currentIndex; i++) {
    getline(ifstream infile, my_book[i].title);
    getline(ifstream infile, my_book[i].author);
    getline(ifstream infile, my_book[i].publisher);
    getline(ifstream infile, my_book[i].price);
    getline(ifstream infile, my_book[i].isbn);
    getline(ifstream infile, my_book[i].pages);
    getline(ifstream infile, my_book[i].copies);
    currentIndex++;
}
```

The text file will have book information listed as such:

```
Magician: Apprentice
Raymond E. Feist
Spectra (January 1, 1994)
5.02
0553564943
512
1
```

Comment: Remove the word `ifstream` infront of `infile`.

Comment: it's a bad practice to do so. write structs to a file and read struct back from files.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Who says so, and why actually? Could you elaborate about this please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the logical way is to write struct/class to a file and read it back to a struct. in his example why didn't he read: infile.read((char*) &book, sizeof(book)); instead

Comment: @kfsone removing ifstream give me the following error:
|error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, char [100])

Comment: @Raindrop7 This would be even more problematic. The correct way is to use de-/serialization. But that's off the scope what's asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - first declare infile outside for loop then use it.

2 - getline(infile, book[i]....) is not infile.getline(book[i]... , size,..)
the first is used with class string and the second is used with array of characters.

so your program may look like:

```
ifstream infile("data.txt", ios::in); // your data file

for (int i=0; i < currentIndex; i++)
{
       infile.getline(my_book[i].title    , 100, '\n');
       infile.getline(my_book[i].author   , 100, '\n');
       infile.getline(my_book[i].publisher, 100, '\n');
       infile >> my_book[i].price;
       infile.getline(my_book[i].isbn     , 100, '\n');
       infile >> my_book[i].pages;
       infile >> my_book[i].copies;
       currentIndex++;
}
```

Comment: This has definitely helped!! Now my output is a little whacky, but I have to go to work and will mess around with it afterward. Thanks!